# Clean way of using ob_start() and ob_end_clean() in wordpress

Tags: shortcode, function-exists

I want to pass some json data to JS from wordpress(PHP) and was thinking to use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` in wordpress but i am not sure weather any other plugins are using the same functions. I was thinking to manually add `ob_start()` at the beginning of the theme header and clear the document when necessary. I thought of using grep find if there are any `ob_start()` in wordpress, but i can't grep find everytime my website gets updated. Are there any workarounds? I will be calling `ob_end_clean()` from a shortcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a whole set of useful functions to handle. It's called [wp_send_json()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/). You have success and error functions too.

`ob_start()`, `ob_get_clean()` would be useful in case you want to include some views (~ MVC) in your shortcode, e.g in your shortcode handler. I don't see here why you would use them to pass data from PHP to js.

Otherwise I would use them in the shortcode handler, no use to put them in theme.